# ajax returns a null request (Undefined index)

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

i have this simple ajax requst

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(() => {
            var val1 = $("#id").val();
            var val2 = $("#dt").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "refreshState.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: { id: val1 , dt:val2 }
            });

        }, 2000);
    });
</script>
```

and this php code

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_REQUEST)) {
require_once("./dbConfig.php");
 $now=date_create(trim($_REQUEST["dt"],"'"));
 $id=$_REQUEST["id"];
 $update_login="UPDATE users set login_time=? where id=?";
 $update_login=$db->prepare($update_login);  
 $update_login->bind_param("ss",$now,$id);
 $update_login->execute();

}
?>
```

**when i load the page i get error that i have no post request**

Undefined index: dt in C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\ten\refreshState.php on line **6**

Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\ten\refreshState.php on line **7**

Comment: `$_REQUEST` will be set regardless use `if (!empty($_REQUEST)) {` or better since you know `if (!empty($_POST)) {`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ($_POST) post method

```
   <?php
session_start();
if ($_POST){
require_once("./dbConfig.php");
 $now=date_create(trim($_POST["dt"],"'"));
 $id=$_POST["id"]; 
 $update_login="UPDATE users set login_time=? where id=?";
 $update_login=$db->prepare($update_login);  
 $update_login->bind_param("ss",$now,$id);
 $update_login->execute();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try $_POST :

```
    session_start();
    if ($_POST){
    require_once("./dbConfig.php");
     $now=date_create(trim($_POST["dt"],"'"));
     $id=$_POST["id"]; 
     $update_login="UPDATE users set login_time=? where id=?";
     $update_login=$db->prepare($update_login);  
     $update_login->bind_param("ss",$now,$id);
     $update_login->execute();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(() => {
            var val1 = $("#id").val();
            var val2 = $("#dt").val();
            var object = {};
            object.id = val1;
            object.dt = val2;
      
            $.ajax({
                url: "refreshState.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: object
            });

        }, 2000);
    });
</script>
```